# jQuery animation problem

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm new to jQuery and learning it to integrate with ASP.NET.

The following is throwing an exception as "Invalid argument".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("h2:first").animate({
            borderBottom: '3px solid #8f8f8f',
            borderRight: '3px solid #bfbfbf'
        }, 2000);
    }
);
```

.....

```
<h2>
    Welcome to ASP.NET!
</h2>
```

Thank you
& regards

Comment: I edited your question title and tags, because it doesn't have anything to do with Asp.net apart from you mentioning it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

You're trying to animate more than one dimension per property.

> All animated properties should be animated to a *single numeric value*, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be.) Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

You have to set values one property at a time like `borderBottomWidth: 3`. The problem is also that provided animation capability isn't able to animate colours as is. You have to resort to other means to do that.

> The [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) project extends the `.animate()` method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.